# Google scripts only run manually, but not automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found similar questions, but none that answer my question that I can tell. I have 5 triggers on a google sheet. Four are copy functions, the other is a mail function. The mail function works fine, but none of the copy functions work unless you force them to run manually. I'm sure it's a code problem, but not sure what. Any help would be appreciated. Here is a copy of my code.

```
function Copy3()   {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Consolidation Client Names 6'); //replace with 
source Sheet tab name
var range = ss.getRange('A1:K1000'); //assign the range you want to copy
var data = range.getValues();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Copied as Values 7'); //replace with
destination Sheet tab name
ts.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: What triggers are they and how did you create them? simple triggers cannot do everything, some actions need installable triggers

Answer (score 0):

Both times when you try to fetch the sheet by the name, you do it with a reference to a variable that was never created/initiated.

```
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Consolidation Client Names 6');
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Copied as Values 7');
```

Neither `sss` nor `tss` have been declared.

Furthermore, you try to declare the `ss` variable three times (two times to save the Active Spreadsheet, and once to save the sheet that you're fetching). I would advise you to give all of them different names (I suppose you wanted to call them `sss` and `tss`).